# How to make the scrollbar appear inside the div's border

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I have a div that has overflow auto. So when the content exceeds the height scrollbars appear. But the problem here is that they appear outside the div which kind of messes up the layout when on mobile.

Now what I want to do is to make the scrollbar appear INSIDE the div's border. How can I do that?

Moreover, another question on the side part is, I am using PHP to create an API for Discord. Now I am not using any framework and just coding in pure PHP. Essentially, is it better to use a framwork or not? (I only like Codeigniter)

Comment: Anyone who helps you, specifically for the first half of your question, will want to see what you've tried. Post some code on here or link an external platform like JSFiddle to show your code.

Comment: essentially I want something like this: http://imgur.com/hVWlc53 in which the scrollbar is inside the box but typically my scrollbar appear a little off from the box

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="row" style="height:100px; overflow-x: auto;">
    *//your content//*
</div>
```